# Could Not Execute Entity Framework Method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I received the following exception:
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not execute the method because either the method itself or the containing type is not fully instantiated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Stack Trace:

Line 98:         SqlParameter userID = new SqlParameter("@UserProfileID", user.ID);

Line 99:         SqlParameter Title = new SqlParameter("@Title", user.FirstName + " Inventory");

Line 100:        Case case1 = Context.Database.SqlQuery("spCasesAdd @UserProfileID, @Title", userID, Title).FirstOrDefault();

Line 101:        tranScope.Complete();

Line 102:      }

Source File: c:\Development\UI\ViewModels\NewAgencyViewModel.cs    Line: 100

System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries() +0
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlNonSetQuery.GetEnumerator() +102
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +41
   System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +152

Code for the class:

```
  public class NewAgencyViewModel
  {
    [Required]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 6)]
    [Display(Name = "Agency Name:")]
    public string AgencyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Contact First Name:")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact Middle Name:")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Last Name:")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Email Address:")]
    [Remote("VerifyUniqueEmail", "Home")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New Password:")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm New Password:")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public void Update(InvContext Context)
    {
      AgencyRepository agencyRepo = new AgencyRepository(Context);
      Agency agency = agencyRepo.Get(-1);
      if (agency == null)
        throw new System.Exception("There Is No Template Agency Available To Process Your Header Image.  Please Try Again Later");
      byte[] headerImage = agency.HeaderImage;
      byte[] backgroundImage = agency.BackgroundImage;

      // Create the Agency
      try
      {
        agency = new Agency();
        agency.Name = AgencyName;
        agency.Email = Email;
        agency.Actve = true;
        agency.HeaderImage = headerImage;
        agency.BackgroundImage = backgroundImage;
        agencyRepo.Add(agency);
        agencyRepo.Save();
        if (agency.ID < 1)
        {
          throw new System.Exception("Your Agency Could Not Be Created.  Please Try Again Later");
        }
      }
      catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
      {
        throw new System.Exception(e.InnerException == null ? e.Message : e.InnerException.Message);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        throw new System.Exception(e.InnerException == null ? e.Message : e.InnerException.Message);
      }

      // Create the new User Profile
      try
      {
        string token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(Email, NewPassword, new
        {
          RegistrationCode = "",
          FirstName = FirstName,
          MiddleName = MiddleName == null ? "" : MiddleName,
          LastName = LastName,
          AgencyID = agency.ID,
          LastLogonDate = SqlDateTime.MinValue,
          Active = true,
          PostDisaster = false
        });
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        throw new System.Exception(e.InnerException == null ? e.Message : e.InnerException.Message);
      }

      // Add the User to the Agent role
      try
      {
        Roles.AddUserToRole(Email, "Agent");
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        throw new System.Exception(e.InnerException == null ? e.Message : e.InnerException.Message);
      }

      // Create the Inventory List for the new User
      try
      {
        UserProfileRepository upRepo = new UserProfileRepository(Context);
        GinkoBL.UserProfile user = upRepo.Get(Email);
        CaseRepository caseRepo = new CaseRepository(Context);

        SqlParameter userID = new SqlParameter("@UserProfileID", user.ID);
        SqlParameter Title = new SqlParameter("@Title", user.FirstName + " Inventory");
        Case case1 = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Case>("spCasesAdd @UserProfileID, @Title", userID, Title).FirstOrDefault();
        if (case1.ID < 1)
        {
          throw new System.Exception("Your Agency Could Not Be Created.  Please Try Again Later");
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        throw new System.Exception(e.InnerException == null ? e.Message : e.InnerException.Message);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Would be useful to see the method that is causing the exception, rather than just the stack trace (e.g. the method of the NewAgencyViewModel class that is being executed).

Comment: Ciaran - I had hoped someone would recognize the exception description, as the code is extensive.  However, I have edited the orignal post to include the entire NewAgencyViewModel class.

Comment: I may be well of the mark here, but shouldn't 'user' be instantiated first? ie. GinkoBL.UserProfile user = new GinkoBL.UserProfile(); then  user = upRepo.Get(Email).

Comment: Lots of code smells here. Long methods indicate bad separation of concerns. Exceptions should not be used to control program flow. A viewmodel should not update, a DAL should. Anonymous objects should not be used as parameters (`CreateUserAndAccount`). Apparently there is a `TransactionScope` somewhere, indicating that yet another method is controlling transactions, again a DAL task. All this makes it very hard to analyse your code on what/where/why something goes wrong.

Comment: Gert - No TransactionScope involved.  However you are correct about the ViewModel not performing an update.  I moved the update out of the ViewModel and that solved the problem.  I'm still puzzled by the lack of documentation on the specific error.

Comment: `tranScope.Complete()`?? Anyway, glad the issue is solved. Try to bring more separation of concerns in your architecture. Loose coupling, little dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

it looks as though you are missing the `exec` command on your `SqlQuery` which would execute the stored procedure rather than try to query a table by that name.

Try:

```
Case case1 = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Case>(
             "exec spCasesAdd @UserProfileID, @Title", userID, Title)
             .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  I resolved this issue by moving the update to business layer.